# Having issues finding an element to serach by to click on with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi I am trying to click on a button which has the following html structure that I found from chrome inspect.

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <button type="submit" tabindex="3" data-ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" data-ng-class="{ 'gray': loginForm.$invalid }">Login</button>
</div>
```

I am not sure what to find the element by. ID, Name, XPath, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the following XPath here:

```
//button[@data-ng-click="login()"]
```

But still need to validate this gives an unique locator

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element element, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default[data-ng-click='login()'][data-ng-class*='loginForm']"))).click();
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-default' and @data-ng-click='login()'][text()='Login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: Using *Python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```